# How to locate a Checkbox item in Datadog synthetic test with Terraform

Tags: testing, checkbox, terraform, datadog, synthetic

I'm building a Datadog's Synthetic Browser test with Terraform, but I'm facing issues to address this HTML element:
`<input type="checkbox" name="payrollInstructionIds" value="957e1f96-377d-4cec-a815-e6ec0e52402d">`

The step I'm trying to do is a click on that checkbox. But, should be considered that the page have 9 checkboxes, and all of them have the same 'type' and 'name' properties. Only 'value' changes.

I have tried with these options, but the test always fails at that step, saying that the element couldn't be located.
**Option 1:**

```
  browser_step {
    name = "Click checkbox: Reg. Salary Pay"
    type = "click"
    params {
      element_user_locator {
        fail_test_on_cannot_locate = "true"
        value {
          type  = "css"
          value = "input[value='957e1f96-377d-4cec-a815-e6ec0e52402d']"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Option 2:**

```
  browser_step {
    name = "Click checkbox: Reg. Salary Pay"
    type = "click"
    params {
      element_user_locator {
        fail_test_on_cannot_locate = "true"
        value {
          type  = "css"
          value = "input[type='checkbox',value='957e1f96-377d-4cec-a815-e6ec0e52402d']"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Option 3:**

```
  browser_step {
    name = "Click checkbox: Reg. Salary Pay"
    type = "click"
    params {
      element_user_locator {
        fail_test_on_cannot_locate = "true"
        value {
          type  = "css"
          value = "input[type='checkbox']"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

All the three options give me this result on the Datadog's GUI:
**Error Cannot locate element.**

Anyone knows how to do it?

Expectation:
The synthetic browser test is able to click the checkbox and continue with the next test's steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing this problem, the solutions is putting all the element's attributes in separated brackets.

For the case presented in the question, the solution would be:

```
    name = "Click checkbox: Reg. Salary Pay"
    type = "click"
    params {
      element_user_locator {
        fail_test_on_cannot_locate = "true"
        value {
          type  = "css"
          value = "input[type='checkbox'][name='payrollInstructionIds'][value='957e1f96-377d-4cec-a815-e6ec0e52402d']"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```